# ant propertyregex, replace string with specified string

Tags: regex, ant, replace

this is my string `com.element.subelement`

I want to use `propertyregex` to replace all `.` with `/`, and use that output as a directory path.

It seemed like propertyregex would be the tool for this, but maybe I am using its `regexp` property incorrectly.

How would I use regex to find the `.` only, I don't want to assume that the string is 3 alphabet portions separated by periods. also perhaps propertyregex is not the tool for the job

here is one that works where I assume that a package name only have 2 periods

```
<!-- set package name to folder directory -->
    <propertyregex 
        property="current.target.dir"
          input="com.element.subelement"
          regexp="(.+?)\.(.+?)\.(.+?)"
          replace="\1/\2/\3"
          casesensitive="false" />

    <echo>${current.target.dir}</echo>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply replacing `\.` with `/` should accomplish what you're looking for, if I understand.  However, this will only replace the first instance on a line by default, so you have to add the property `global="true"`:

```
<propertyregex 
    property="current.target.dir"
      input="com.element.subelement"
      regexp="\."
      replace="/"
      global="true" />
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that `defaultvalue` should be used in case the regexp doesn't match anything. Not really applicable in this case, but I just wasted 1/2h on finding out why the resulting property was empty :)